# Extended SqlProfileProvider, how do I call my custom method?

Tags: c#, sqlprofileprovider

I'm using `MySqlProfileProvider` which extends the `SqlProfileProvider` class. In my class I am overriding `Initialize` in order to change the connection string of the base. This all works absolutely fine.

My problem is that I need to make a call after the profile provider has been initialized to change the connection string (when it's initializing I don't have the required information to create the correct connection string), and I can't seem to access the method.

It works in my custom `SqlMembershipProvider` class, in order to call the function I call

```
((MySqlMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers).ChangeConnectionString(sRequiredData);
```

The class:

```
public class MySqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config) {...}

    public virtual void ChangeConnectionString(string sRequiredData)
    {
        // get db name 
        string sDATABASE_NAME = ManageDBs.GetCompanyDBName(sRequiredData);

        // Set private property of Membership provider. 
        FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        string connectionString = connectionStringField.GetValue(this).ToString();

        if (!connectionString.Contains(sDATABASE_NAME))
        {
            connectionString = connectionString.Replace("DATABASE_NAME", sDATABASE_NAME);

            connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the same method in my profile provider but I cannot find how to call it. I've tried accessing it in `ProfileBase`, `ProfileProvider` and `Profile` with no luck and there doesn't seem to be anyone on google with the solution.

**EDIT**

I'm looking for something that looks akin to

```
((MySqlProfileProvider)Profile.Provider).ChangeConnectionString(sRequiredData);
```

but unfortunately you can't access `Provider` through profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by trial and error:

```
((MySqlProfileProvider)ProfileBase.Properties["ANY_PROFILE_PROPERTY"].Provider).ChangeConnectionString(sRequiredData);
```